# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Angular/Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I'm trying to add an array of `Funcionarios` objects into a `Equipa` object, but when i try to `push` a `new Funcionarios` it pops and this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, i have gone over the code several times and initialized all variables, but it keeps always giving me the same error.

```
export class Funcionarios {
    id : Number;
    codFunc: Number;
    nomeFunc: string;

    constructor(codFunc: Number, nomeFunc: string) {
        this.codFunc = codFunc;
        this.nomeFunc = nomeFunc;
    }
}

export class Equipa {
    id : Number;
    codEquipa: Number;
    nomeEquipa: string;
    ocorFuncs: Funcionarios[] = [];

    constructor(id : Number, codEquipa: Number, nomeEquipa: string, funcs: Funcionarios[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.codEquipa = codEquipa;
        this.nomeEquipa = nomeEquipa;
        this.ocorFuncs = funcs;
    }
}

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    equipa: Equipa = new Equipa(null, null, null, null);

    ngOnInit() {
        this.equipa.ocorFuncs.push(new Funcionarios(1, "qwe"));
        this.equipa.ocorFuncs.push(new Funcionarios(2, "asd"));
        this.equipa.ocorFuncs.push(new Funcionarios(3, "zxc"));
    }
}
```

Comment: try pushing in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: @Luca, sorry but it's not the answer

Comment: equipa: Equipa = new Equipa(null, null, null, []);

Comment: @Eliseo yes, right! My misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you see what you are truing to do right now.

You want to push value to the `null`, `null` have no push method. 
if you change this declaration line to

```
equipa: Equipa = new Equipa(null, null, null, []);
```

it will work fine, checked on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Equipa` assigns `ocorFuncs` with whatever comes from the parameter `funcs` which in your case is `null`, and thus overrides the value you initialize the field with. You should check if the parameter is null and leave the default value if the parameter is null:

```
export class Equipa {
    id : Number;
    codEquipa: Number;
    nomeEquipa: string;
    ocorFuncs: Funcionarios[] = [];

    constructor(id : Number, codEquipa: Number, nomeEquipa: string, funcs: Funcionarios[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.codEquipa = codEquipa;
        this.nomeEquipa = nomeEquipa;
        this.ocorFuncs = funcs || this.ocorFuncs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your `Equipa` object like so:

`new Equipa(null, null, null, null);`

The fourth argument, to initialize `ocorFuncs` is passed as `null` so:

`this.equipa.ocorFuncs.push(new Funcionarios(3, "zxc"))`

is invoking `push` on an object that has not been initialised correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `equipa` with `null` values. So after calling
 `new Equipa(null, null, null, null)`

it is setting them inside the constructor as `null`

`this.ocorFuncs = funcs;`

try initializing it with an empty array

`equipa: Equipa = new Equipa(null, null, null, []);`